# Understanding loop-level parallelism

Tags: opengl, glsl

I just stumbled upon the term "loop-level parallelism" and am trying to understand it. I am using OpenGL.

Say, I have some algorithm that calculates some approximation that gets better with each iteration. If I wrote code like this, the compiler wouldn't know the number of iterations and thus this loop would be "slow":

```
while (ErrTol_not_met)
{
    // Do iteration step
}
```

If I wrote this code like this, it would be faster?

```
for (int n = 0; n < N; n++)
{
    // Do iteration step
}
```

Of course the first loop would always meet the error tolerance while the second loop would - dependent on N - maybe sometime meet the tolerance, sometimes do unneccesary calculations. I just want to understand this in principal.

Do I understand "loop-level parallelism" correctly? Is there anything special to know, how OpenGL handels this? What kind of speedup could be expected if I rewrite some loops? In what cases / what kind of loops would this be relevant at all?

Comment: Are we talking about shader code? If not, then how is OpenGL related to the problem?

Comment: Please also provide references where you read about loop-level parallelism and that it's a compiler feature. I'm quite sure that the concept you have in mind isn't correct. 1) I don't think that any compiler automatically parallelizes loops. 2) loop-level parallelism usually only works with fully independent task, but approximations usually need to result of the previous iteration to calculate the next one, so not independent.

Comment: OK, so first of all: Yes, this is about shader code. My above example was obviously a bad one. Like I said - I want to understand "loop-level parallelism". I don't even remember where I read it and I don't know, if this is a compiler feature. I simply want to understand if in some cases it might be beneficial to write certain loops in a way so that - if it IS a compiler feature - the compiler can speedup execution.

Comment: `for` loop is a syntax sugar for a `while` loop. And I don't think compilers treat them in a special way. Meaning writing `for` instead of `while` shouldn't affect anything. I might be wrong though. Moreover this kind of optimizations dependens on the compiler - I don't think C/C++ standard mandates anything here. So what I suggest you actually test and benchmark it yourself.

Comment: Short answer: 1) There is no loop level parallelism in shaders. 2) Shader execution has a different execution model than "regular" code, because it executes the same instruction on several data entries at the same time. So the code might not get as much speed up from that when a large number of threads needs to wait for a single thread with higher iteration count. But that isn't solved by increasing the number of iterations for all threads. You might get some benefits when you group threads with similar iteration count together, but that's probably not working for approximation algorithms.

Comment: @freakish: For loops with constant iteration count might be unrolled (while loops can't be unrolled that easily), if that results in any performance gain needs to be measured. Also note, that depending on the hardware and OpenGL version, loops with dynamic count might not be supported (although that's rarely the case nowadays).

Comment: @BDL as long as the `while` loop correctly corresponds to `for` (which as I said: is just a fancy `while` loop) I'm pretty sure it can be unrolled just as easily. So I suppose the question is more about whether the iteration count is bounded/constant (and known to the compiler), rather than whether we should use `for` instead of `while`.

Comment: @BDL so "loop-level parallelism" would apply for example if I iterated through an array and did something (independently) with its elements? And that again would not apply to shaders, because here each element would get its own thread (more or less) anyway and there would be no iteration (or maybe a small one)? To your 2): I should get somewhat of a speedup, if I limit the number of iterations, so that finished threads wouldn't have to wait for one loop with higher iteration-count, right? So "try N times, then give up"...

Comment: 1) Yes, 2) Depends on how you implement it. If you start one shader invocation for each item, then yes. If you start one iteration and write a for loop over the elements, then no. 3) Might be, but I wouldn't expect much, unless the iteration count differs a lot or if the amount of work in the loop is very large.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is that for loops can be unrolled by the compiler if N is an uniform value or known at compilation time.